# Mysql Error 1273 when moving DB from dev to live server

Tags: mysql, database, update, joomla-3.6

So, I recently updated to version 3.6.5. I initially tested the update on a test server before moving the update to my live server. The issue I'm running into is Mysql 1273 
Error

```
CREATE TABLE `zyjgk_assets` (
`id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
`parent_id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set parent.',
`lft` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',
`rgt` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',
`level` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',
`name` varchar( 50 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',
`title` varchar( 100 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',
`rules` varchar( 5120 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.',
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` ( `name` ) ,
KEY `idx_lft_rgt` ( `lft` , `rgt` ) ,
KEY `idx_parent_id` ( `parent_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =362 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Googling around suggests that there is some sort incompatibility between the Mysql versions on the test and live servers, so how do I proceed from here and fix this?

Comment: The answer may be in the the answer I answered for you in this other question that you ignored. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/fix-database-after-failed-update/18644#18644 I suggest if you keep asking questions and want help that you should asknowledge those who try to help you.

Comment: @norcaljohnny sorry for taking so long to acknowledge your post, I have been playing "whack-a-mole" with issues and trying to address these and other problems around a busy schedule. I'm sure you can appreciate how life can get in the way of things. I appreciated your well-illustrated post, but as I stated in my reply, your proposed solution wasn't an option and I will have to use part of your solution (look for a back up) as part of resolving all of this. In fact, the second poster spotted the DB table issues as a possible solution to move forward, and I will have to evaluate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SQL file that you're uploading to `phpMyAdmin`, then try doing a find and replace. Replace `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` with `utf8_general_ci`, **and then** replace `utf8mb4` with `utf8`, and then try uploading the file again.

Note: the above is not tested - but it should work. If possible, please post back your findings here so that others can learn from your experience.